# Prevent active status change in on_active callback

Tags: android, python, switch-statement, widget, kivy

## My Goal

In my Kivy App for Android, I have a Switch widget that creates a Bluetooth socket connection when it is turned on. When turned off, it closes the socket. The callback is executed with the on_active option.

The idea is that when turned on, the callback checks whether a connection has been stablished. If yes, then the switch changes its value. If no, a popup appears and the switch goes back to "active=False" value.

**My problem** is that I cannot prevent the Switch widget changing to "Active=True" when the Bluetooth connection is not stablished.

**The question**: is it possible to prevent the "Active" status change inside a "on_active" callback?

I have looked around in the documentation and many other examples in the Internet, but without success. I am a newbie with kivy/python and any help would be much appreciated.

## Already tried

1. I have tried to bind the active property to a variable of the App loop. This approach works with other buttons, but when called within the "on_active" callback, the active status does not change.
   It seems that the binded variable value does not update (from False to True) until the callback is finished. Therefore, I cannot use this approach, because "app.activeSwitch=False" is later overruled by the callback action
2. The other approach that I have also tried is to pass the "pointer of the switch" (i think is called pointer) to the callback, and then change the status through it. The app crashes with this approach.
3. I have thought of using a Clock.schedule_once with a timer or before the next frame, but this is a bad solution.
4. My last thought was to try to interrupt the callback or use "return False", but it did not work.

## Code basics

The Kv File

```
    <ClassName>:
        BoxLayout:
          Switch:
             on_active: app.setBluetoothConnection(self.active)
              active: app.activeBluetooth
```

The Python File:

```
 class MainLoop(App):
    activeBluetooth=BooleanProperty(False)

    #Here comes build with other Widget building and callbacks

    def setBluetoothConnection(self,activeValue):
      if activeValue == True:
          try:
                #Check whether we can connect and stablish connection
          except:
                #Error-Popup                        
                popup = Popup(content=content, title='Connection,error',size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))
                popup.open()

                #What can I define here to prevent the active status change of the switch?#

           else:
                #Close the socket connection and other stuff
```

## Summing up

I think that there has to be a very easy solution to this problem without changing lots of parts of the code...

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE To the issue

Thanks to a suggestion/tip by @John Anderson, I have figured out what was making my programm crash. The following is a solution to the problem, but **still it is not a very elegant solution**:

-**Problem**: when defining  `activeSwitch.active=False` **within** the **on_active callback**, the programm called again the callback. Since the *socket* variable of the bluetooth connection does not exist when there is no connection, i was calling an inexistent variable.

### Workaround solution

The kv file

```
  <ClassName>:
        BoxLayout:
          Switch:
             on_active: app.setBluetoothConnection(self)
              active: False
```

The Python File:

```
 class MainLoop(App):
    #Here comes build with other Widget building and callbacks

    def setBluetoothConnection(self,activeSwitch):
      if activeSwitch.active == True:
          try:
                self.recv_stream, self.send_stream, self.socket = get_socket_stream('connectionBluetooth')   #DIALOG-SPS
          except:
                #Error-Popup                        
                popup = Popup(content=content, title='Connection,error',size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))
                popup.open()

                activeSwitch.active=False

       else:
           try:
                self.socket.close() #close the socket connection

           except:
                pass
```

The following code is a workaround the problem, but it is non-optimal since the callback is called **twice** when `if activeSwitch.active == True` and `except:` is entered.

For the shake of knowing, it would be great if someone comes across a more elegant solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `activeBluetooth` property in your `App` class?

Comment: The status of the `Switch` will not change unless you do something to change it. It does not automatically switch back to 'True".

Comment: Hi @John Anderson: `activeBluetooth` is there just as part of a trial to prevent the switch changing the value when the bluetooth connection is not stablished. I could get rid of it.

2 Point: The idea is to *prevent* the active status change to *active* when the bluetooth connection is not stablished. That is, the switch go back to *active=False*

Comment: To _prevent_ the status change inside the `on_active callback`. (sorry for the formatting, i have been playing around, and i could not edit the comment again)

Comment: Your line in the `kv` file `active: app.activeBluetooth` sets a binding between the `active` property of the `Switch` and the `activeBluetooth` property of your `MainLoop`. That binding will adjust the `active` property of the `Switch` to agree with the `activeBluetooth` property. I think it would be better to not have that property and binding.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what I think is your problem. Your `else` statement in `setBluetoothConnection()` is acting as part of a `try, except, else` block. I think you intended the `else` to be matched with the `if`. So you need to unindent the `else` block. It would simplify your code to pass the `Switch` instance to your `setBluetoothConnection()` instead of just the `active` value:

`kv`:

```
<ClassName>:
    BoxLayout:
      Switch:
         # pass the Switch instance to the setBluetoothConnection() method
         on_active: app.setBluetoothConnection(self)
         active: False
```

python code:

```
 class MainLoop(App):
    #Here comes build with other Widget building and callbacks

    def setBluetoothConnection(self,switch_instance):
      if switch_instance.active == True:
          try:
                #Check whether we can connect and stablish connection
          except:
                #Error-Popup                        
                popup = Popup(content=content, title='Connection,error',size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))
                popup.open()

                #What can I define here to prevent the active status change of the switch?#

       # note the indentation matches the above `if` statement
       else:
            #Close the socket connection and other stuff
            switch_instance.active = False
```

Comment: Hi @John. Thank you for your answer. The `else` indentation was only a mistake in the code that i have posted: it was correctly written in the app. However, thanks to your suggestion, I have player a little bit with the code, and I found a workaround solution. Check the **Update of the issue** in the original post please.